# How to hash system time in c++ using SHA1 hashing algorithm?

Tags: c++, hash, openssl, sha1

I was trying to hash system time in c++. I calculated the system time using the chrono library this way.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include<ctime>
int main()
{
    auto timenow = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::now());
    std::cout<<"The time is "<<ctime(&timenow)<<std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

But I am facing problem in hashing this time. In converting this time into a unique hash string using SHA1 hashing algorithm.

I tried including the library `#include "sha1.h"` and  `#include<openssl/sha1.h>`. But these didn't work
(openssl library is installed). Can someone please help me figuring out the correct method of doing so?

Comment: This seems to be a configuration problem and doesn't seen to be related to the chrono lib. Perhaps pertinent system details might be useful. As it currently stands, "doesn't work" isn't much to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `#include <openssl/sha.h>` for all the available secure hash algorithms.

That will give you access to all these functions:

```
 int SHA1_Init(SHA_CTX *c);
 int SHA1_Update(SHA_CTX *c, const void *data, size_t len);
 int SHA1_Final(unsigned char *md, SHA_CTX *c);
 unsigned char *SHA1(const unsigned char *d, size_t n,
                     unsigned char *md);
```

In which case, you can likely just do the one-shot invoke of:

```
unsigned char result[20] = {};
SHA1(const char*)&timenow, sizeof(timenow), result);
```

Or the long way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {

   // time_t can be 32-bit or 64-bit
   // so force timenow to be 64-bit, so we'll have consistent
   // hash values across different machine architectures

   uint64_t timenow = time(nullptr);
   unsigned char result[20]={};

   // hash it
   SHA_CTX ctx = {};
   SHA1_Init(&ctx);
   SHA1_Update(&ctx, (const char*)&timenow, sizeof(timenow));
   SHA1_Final(result, &ctx);

   // print the result
   std::cout << "Current unix epoch time is " << timenow << std::endl;
   for (auto x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
       std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (unsigned int)(result[x]);
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;
};
```

Don't forget to link with the crypto library , `-lcrypto`

Example compile and run:

```
$ g++ source.cpp -lcrypto -o demo

$ ./demo
Current unix epoch time is 1601974311
cc227522246af31e4c9bff9d3f78166f62a19695

$ ./demo
Current unix epoch time is 1601974314
15d03343855d674330cbfc5dc435cc3d320e2788
```

Also, what are you really trying to?  A hash of a time_t timestamp isn't very interesting or secure by itself. It can be trivially reversed given that there's only about 1 billion seconds since Jan 1, 1970.

Comment: It seems some parenthesis are imbalanced in second code block, please correct it . I think you answer will be very useful. I was trying to implement time hash in a small project.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the significance of `size_t n` in `unsigned char *SHA1(const unsigned char *d, size_t n,unsigned char *md);`

Comment: The first parameter to `SHA` is a pointer to the memory buffer you want to hash.  In this case, you want to hash the time, so it's a pointer to your `timenow` variable.  The second parameter is the number of bytes that first parameter address "points" to.  i.e. how many bytes to hash.  Third parameter is the pointer address for the output to be written to, in this case, a 20-byte array called `result`

Comment: I don't see any typos in my code samples.  However, I did amend the answer to give yo a complete program.  Compile the above with `g++ source.cpp -lcrypto` to build and link.